# SAE J1939 stack

Tags: c

I am trying to build a SAE j1939 protocol but don't know the complete needs. I have Renesas S7G2 and SAME51J19A boards and I need a SAE J1939 stack for this boards. I downloaded some stacks from Github but I don't know how to use this stacks.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is too broad for the site. Try to ask a question about a specific problem you are encountering. The more narrow the problem, the better. Also please note that tool/library recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: (That being said, number 1 is to get CAN up and running on the MCU, then figure out the interface between the stack and the CAN driver. Sometimes stacks come with specific hardware support, sometimes they don't.)